# Страница не хочет прокручиваться в низ

Tags: html, css, прокрутка

Всем привет!
Моя страница не хочет прокручиваться в низ совершенно!

Вот код body:

```css
 display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #efeae4, #ebe1d1);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  animation: pageInAnimation 1.75s;
  overflow: scroll;
```

А ещё такаяже проблема с PopUp:

```css
 top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    color:black;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100vh;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:10px;
    animation:instructions 0.75s;
    border: 5px solid #2c85a4;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
```

Буду признателен, если поможете!

Comment: `height: 100%;` логично что не хочет :) (надеюсь намек понятен?)

Comment: Убрал, не помогло

Comment: Приведите пример чтобы можно было понять где еще у вас ограничена высота блока или отключены скролы :)  с перечисленными вами свойствами - все нормально (кроме возможно overflow: scroll, который должен заставить появится оба скрола в боди) :) https://jsfiddle.net/k6pr4am8/

Comment: В том то и дело,что это только одна страница, и больше пока что страниц у меня нету в моём проекте

Comment: Посмотрите на ссылку выше, там ваш css и со скролами всё окей, проблема не в приведенном вами коде а где то еще :)

Comment: Буду стараться искать

Comment: А можно полный код? Если вы думаете что `PopUp` будет растягивать `body` - то нет, потому что он `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` т.е. дальше нижней границы вьюпорта он не уйдёт. Да и не растянет `body` в целом..

Comment: @Realman а зачем sticky для body?)